# Recyclerview inside nestedscrollview abruptly cuttng

Tags: android

Created Recyclerview inside the nextedscrollview. Displaying recylerview abruptly cuts at the first item in the recyclerview. But when I rotate the phone in landscape mode, and rotate back to portrait mode, the recyclerview list is shown correctly with the scrolling. Can someone please point out what is going wrong here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".form.FragmentFormSummary">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                </Spinner>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:clipChildren="false">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use NestedScroll view as wrapper to RecyclerView. This is not good practice.

You should use RecyclerView ViewTypes instead:  https://medium.com/@gilbertchristopher/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-22619a5ad365

Comment: What is RecyclerView ViewTypes?

Comment: This is the way where you separate your views in recycler view on different types. 
For example you should make a screen where you have different unknown quantity views that will be not the same and user should scroll it. So instead of using the Recycler view inside the nested scroll view - create the different views for each type of view and viewholders for it, The rest will be the same as we use RecyclerView for one type of views.

Answer (score 0):

you need add

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to you recycler view

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.